# Can't install rmagic due to the dependencies errors

Tags: 13.04, dependencies, gcc

I can't install rmagic due to the dependencies errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
Reading package lists... Done
//...............
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickwand-dev : Depends: libmagickwand5 (= 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2) but 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libmagickcore5-extra (= 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2) but 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libmagickcore-dev (= 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have the last version of gcc. I also did

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
sudo apt-get update
```

That didn't help me. What should I do?

Comment: I had such things couple of times it is resolvable. I used Synaptic package manager to clean such a mess what I did I found all those packages and completely removed them and re-installed you can do this using Terminal of course if one of the packages still won't install you might have ppa conflicts happened to me I added 2 ppas that had the same packages available and there was a conflict depends on xxxx but xxxx is to be installed after I removed one of causing ppa and run `autoremove` everything installed with no problems!

Comment: @JohnyD., what should I remove?

Comment: did you try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)?

Comment: @Alex read a link provided by Avinash Raj! in that post is exactly what I've told you. You need to take off causing ppa which one you should know it yourself what ppas you added to your system read all that post along marked "green tick" I'll hope you understand it. I solved my going to Synaptic and typed <packagename> that didn't won't to install and I got a duplicate in a result, 2 packages of the same kind just from different builds from different ppas, so I removed one of those ppas and it worked 100%

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/223237/)